# Navigation bar is not transparent in landscape mode over KitKat(4.4)

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I make the navigation bar transparent in landscape?
It works in portrait.
My device version is Kitkat(Nexus5)

The Youtube Kids works in KitKat.

[image: portrait image it works]

[image: landscape image it doesn't work]

Comment: You can change navigation and status bar colors (also to transparent) only from Lollipop+

Comment: @krossovochkin
Lollipop is too.

Comment: Can you post your `AppTheme` details from **style.xml** ?

Comment: @pRaNaY


My `AppTheme` is default.

`<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.
We cannot set a color to navigation bar in landscape under lollipop.
But we can set transpalent temporarily these version.
You set the flag which is View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY.

`setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);`

Comment: Where I should set this flag? I would be grateful for a piece of code.

Comment: I set `getWindow().addFlags(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);